# how to make jQuery plugin return the wrapped set?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

how can we make the jQuery plugnin to return the wrapped set?so that using the plugin does not make the code loose the chaining property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
return this;
```

To the end of your function.